# jQuery not a function error when writing custom object

Tags: jquery, function, object

I'm trying to develop one of my first jQuery objects:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var WNM = function (element) {
        var elem = $(element);
        var obj = this;

        var MultipleValues = function (element) {
            var elem = $(element);
            var obj = this;
            var opt; // Options;
            var sep; // Seperator string;
            var vals; // Array wich holds the values;

            //$(obj).find(".multipleValuesSett_MaxItems").val();

            this.MultipleValues = function (options) {
                opt = options;
                sep = $(obj).find(".multipleValuesSett_Seperator").val();

                loadValues();

                outputValues();
            };

            var loadValues = function () {
                var values = $(obj).find(".multipleValues_Values").val();
                vals = values.split(sep);
            };

            var outputValues = function () {
                var temp;
                if ($.isFunction(opt.output)) {
                    temp = opt.output.apply(this, vals);
                    $(obj).find(".multipleValues_ValuesOutput")
                        .append(temp);
                }
            };
        };

        this.MultipleValues = function (options) {
            if (elem.length) {
                var mv = new MultipleValues(elem);
                mv.MultipleValues(options);
                return mv;
            }
            else
                return null;
        };

    };

    $.fn.MultipleValues = function () {
        return wnm = new WNM(this);
    };

});
```

Now whenever I try to run this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".multipleValues").WNMedia().MultipleValues({
        output: function (data) {
            var temp = "";
            temp += "<ul>";
            $.each(data, function (i) {
                temp += "<li>" + data[i] + "</li>";
            });
            temp += "<ul>";

            return temp;
        }
    });
});
```

I get the following error: (TypeError: $(".multipleValues").WNMedia() is not a function). Can someone help me out here please, I'm kind of stuck..

=========================================

Now I have another issue.. You can see that in de defined output function, I call the option output function. A param vals is passed, which is an array of strings. Whenever I loop through the data var, it contains only one item, while in fact there are three.. Any ideas?

Solved the issue, changed:

```
temp = opt.output.apply(null, vals);
```

into:

```
temp = opt.output.apply(null, [vals]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you never defined WNMedia(), your sample [works](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/VHg4Z/) in following

```
$(".multipleValues").MultipleValues({
        output: function (data) {
            var temp = "";
            temp += "<ul>";
            $.each(data, function (i) {
                temp += "<li>" + data[i] + "</li>";
            });
            temp += "<ul>";

            return temp;
        }
    });
​
```

Comment: Thnx for the quick response! This solved my issue!! Thnx man!

Comment: Now i have another issue.. You can see that in de defined output function, i call the option output function. A param vals is passed, wich is an array of strings. Whenever i loop through the data var, it contains only one item, while in fact there are three.. Any ideas?

Comment: may be to start another question ? also , use console.log(data) in callback function, to debug

Comment: Ok thnx i'll post a new question. Whenever i write data to consol the value is 1 item of a string. Whenever i write vals to consol its an array with 3 items.